# bash 3.2 vs 4.2: what's up in this scenario where 3.2 $1 captures what 4.2 treats as multiple parameters?

Tags: bash, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I can't find any references explaining bash 3.2 vs 4.2 differences in how function parameters are handled that explains the difference below. I need something that boils down to this issue to work the same on both versions, anyone have a solution, explanation or reference?

```
$ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 3.2.52(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)
$ foo() { echo "One: $1    Two: $2"; }
$ foo $(echo a b)
One: a b    Two:
```

vs

```
$ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
$ foo() { echo "One: $1    Two: $2"; }
$ foo $(echo a b)
One: a    Two: b
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess in the first case, the subshell's output is turned into one argument with a space in it ($1 == "a b") , while in the second the newline in the subshell's output is split on newlines and so it results in two separate arguments pased to foo. It may also depend on what $IFS is.

Comment: I said newline but it is a space. IFS has nothing to do with it. The old case is what you would expect if you quoted the subshell: `foo "$(echo 1 2)"`. So I think what happens is that bash used to implicitly quote the results of subshell substitutions, and now it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking I might smell implicit quotes there. I tried a few manipulations inside the definition of foo to get around it but couldn't find the right incantation.

Comment: I don't have bash version 3.2.52(1) handy, but I tried with 3.2.52(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13) as well as 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0) and 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14), and got the expected result ($1 = "a", $2 = "b") on all of them. I think something else is going on here...

Comment: bleah, ok it was $IFS. I think some code in a function definition I was playing with escaped into the shell itself in a tragic copy/paste accident or something, and altered $IFS. When I tried in a fresh 3.2 shell it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It was $IFS, which seems to have been altered at some point in history. Note to self, always test weird shell behavior in a fresh shell.